# Error msg when i open the „System Info“ in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I have updated sonarqube 5.3 up to sonarqube 5.6.6.
The update process passed without errors.

When I open the “System Info” site in sonarqube then I get a empty site.
In the sonarqube logfile “sonar.log” there are an error message like this:

> ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request https://sonarserver/sonar/api/system/info
>   at org.sonar.server.platform.monitoring.ProcessSystemInfoClient.connect(ProcessSystemInfoClient.java:58) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
>       at org.sonar.server.platform.ws.InfoAction.writeJson(InfoAction.java:81) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
>       at org.sonar.server.platform.ws.InfoAction.handle(InfoAction.java:66) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
>       at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:107) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor174.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
>       at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:425) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
>       at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:292) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
>       at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:44) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
>       at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:70) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]

When I open the URL: https://sonarserver/sonar/api/system/info in Browser, then i get the error message: 
**{"errors":[{"msg":"Can not get system info of process [key='ce', ipcIndex=3]"}]}**

The OS is openSUSE 12.4 (64 Bit).

I Use java SE 8u91 and MySQL 5.6.35

The sonarqube extensions are:

- sonar-crowd-plugin-2.0.jar
- sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.4.4.jar
- sonar-java-plugin-4.5.0.8398.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar

Does anybody know where is the problem?